# How to fix this SQL statement so I can use it to create a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble with the following SQL Statement:

```
CREATE VIEW vMissing_year_students AS
         SELECT sid, 
                first_name, 
                last_name, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(missing_years ORDER BY missing_years) AS missing_years
         FROM ( SELECT s.sid, s.first_name, s.last_name, 2014 'missing_years'
                FROM Students s 
                WHERE s.sid NOT IN ( SELECT sid FROM Students_Courses WHERE year = 2014)
             UNION ALL
                SELECT s.sid, s.first_name, s.last_name, 2015
                FROM Students s 
                WHERE s.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM Students_Courses WHERE year = 2015)
             UNION ALL
                SELECT s.sid, s.first_name, s.last_name, 2016
                FROM Students s 
                WHERE s.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM Students_Courses WHERE year = 2016)
             UNION ALL
                SELECT s.sid, s.first_name, s.last_name, 2017
                FROM Students s 
                WHERE s.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM Students_Courses WHERE year = 2017)
                ) missing 
GROUP BY sid, first_name, last_name;
```

When I try to create this statement as a view, I am given an error saying "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause". I know to fix this I have to change the structure of the query (because I am running an older version of MySQL) but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using ? It is allowed on [MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) *A view can be created from many kinds of SELECT statements. It can refer to base tables or other views. It can use joins, UNION, and subqueries.*

Comment: *Before MySQL 5.7.7, subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view* [Restrictions on Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

Comment: you can create one view and then use it in the other... may be